# PHP, SELECT does not return a value after insert in same script

Tags: php, mysql

Here is an easy one, but can't figure out why is not working. Need another set of eyes.
3 queries. 1 insert, 1 select, then 1 insert again. My select query is supposed to grab a value from the data recently inserted, and then store that value in a variable, then run the second insert for another table. Well, everything works, except the select. I even tryied to add a mysql_query("COMMIT",$conn) and still nothing.
Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks!!!

```
$customerQ = "INSERT INTO
customerData(fname, mname, lname, email, homePhone, cellphone, address, 
city, county, state, zip, gascompany, eleccompany, addedBy)
VALUES('$fname', '$mname', '$lname', '$emailCustomer', '$hphone', '$cellphone',
  '$address', '$city', '$county', '$state', '$zip', '$gas', '$electric', 
  '$userName'
) ";             
//General WO# calculation
$calcWO = "SELECT 
              auditRequest.workOrderNum
            FROM
              auditRequest
            ORDER BY
               auditRequest.workOrderNum DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ";  

//General Customer number calculation. For the Work Order Insert
$calc = "SELECT
              customerData.custnumber
           FROM
              customerData
           WHERE
              fname = '$fname' and
              mname = '$mname' and
              lname = '$lname'
           ORDER BY
           customerData.custnumber DESC
           LIMIT 1
     "; 

    //Customer Information Insert (from Insert Query)
    $resultCustQ = mysql_query($customerQ, $connection);
    mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection); //make sure to commit to be able to query new records
    // Test the query
    if(!$resultCustQ) die ("error 1". mysql_error());

    //Customer Information Insert (from Insert Query)
    $resultCustQ = mysql_query($customerQ, $connection);
    mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection); //make sure to commit to be able to query new records
    // Test the query
    if(!$resultCustQ) die ("error 1". mysql_error());

    //Calculate new customer number
    $calc_result = mysql_query($calc, $connection);
    // Test the query
    if(!$calc_result) die ("error 1". mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($calc_result);
    $custnum = $row['custnumber']; // This is the new Customer.

    //Work Order Information (run SQL Insert)
    $resultWOQ = mysql_query($workOrderQ, $connection);
// Test the query
    if(!$resultWOQ) die ("error 1". mysql_error());
```

Comment: Can you try this with hardcoded query strings, rather than dynamically-generated ones?  (And on that theme, you are exposing yourself to SQL injection here.)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your script is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.  Depending on where the variables are getting their value.

Comment: ok, disregard sql injection. I have taken care of the user input cleaning already. This is just part of the code I am using, where it is breaking. (Oli) I did try hardcoded strings as well without a result. Basically is a function that runs several scripts, but after that specific insert I cannot query that newly inserted record.

Comment: Ok, but try to isolate the problem.  Like I said, does this work with hardcoded queries?

Comment: no it does not either. Basically everything works, except that select statement. I cannot retrieve that last inserted record. and like I said, I tried that "COMMIT" as well with no result

Comment: How do you know everything else worked?  Have you checked the contents of the table with an independent mechanism, e.g. MySQL Admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid the crutch of `INSERT` followed by `SELECT` to find the inserted record altogether and use MySQL's ability to return the ID of the most recently inserted row (provided your table as an `AUTO INCREMENT` primary key) via PHP's [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php), also available through PDO via [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: let me try that. I think that is the solution.